# Launch configuration for an Eclipse RCP project

Tags: eclipse, bundle, rcp

I am new to Eclipse and have been asked to make some changes to an RCP project. Now I can not get it to run. Unfortunately I cannot contact the author to get some help. I would appreciate an hint which could lead to the solution. When I lunch the application I get following log message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.team.core.nl1_3.3.0.I20070607.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.core.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.team.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.nl1_2.3.0.v200706262000.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui_[2.0.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.team.ui.nl1_3.3.0.I20070607.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.rcp.nl1_3.2.0.v20070612.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.rcp.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.rcp_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.ui.win32.nl1_3.2.100.I20070319-0010.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.win32.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.ui.win32_[3.2.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.nl1_2.3.0.v200706262000.jar [29] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui_[2.0.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.team.ui.nl1_3.3.0.I20070607.jar [45] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.ui.win32.nl1_3.2.100.I20070319-0010.jar [66] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.win32.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.ui.win32_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.team.core.nl1_3.3.0.I20070607.jar [83] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.core.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.team.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.rcp.nl1_3.2.0.v20070612.jar [124] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.rcp.nl1 2 0 2012-11-07 09:03:45.878
!MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.rcp_[3.2.0,4.0.0).

I am using a windows 7 Enterprise 64 (4GB) and Eclipse Juno 64.
```

Answer (score 0):

Open launch configuration (Run--> Run Configuration) and Select your launch configuration.
Go to Plugin Tab and click on 'Validate plugins'. you should see all missing plugins there. keep adding missing plugins.

Comment: Thank you reddy, when I try to add the missing plugins as you described. I get the following problem for 4 plugins. 
For example: org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui.nl1: Missing constraint: Fragement-Host:org..ui; bundle=version="{[2.0.0,4.00)"
Do you know what that means?

Comment: I think it is something to do with OS platform specific (not able to find fragment). pls check that you have proper delta pack plugins for 32-bit,64-bit. Pls accept answer if you find it useful